# I need a better way to change a var to true or false

Tags: javascript

I am currently checking a variable, and changing it's value as follows.

Is there a simpler way?

show_centre_switcher = (show_centre_switcher) ? false : true;

Comment: What is wrong with this code that you think you need a "better" way?

Comment: @Claies nothing wrong, just looking for something shorter :)

Answer (score 6):

```
showCenterSwitcher = !showCenterSwitcher;
```

`!` = logic inversion

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to toggle it from true to false and viceversa, this will work and is simpler:

```
show_centre_switcher = !show_centre_switcher;
```